# Big Decimal conversion issue

Tags: java, scale, bigdecimal, rounding

Hi using HALF_EVEN rounding (Banking rounding)  It seems like the rounding off in java is not working as expected. Both the below print should give the same output as 250335.62 but second print is giving as 250335.63. 
please suggest

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("250335.625").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("250335.6250294325406169060513303508358832").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));
```

Comment: Why do you expect the second one to give you `250335.62`?

Comment: .6250294... should "round up", after all it's closer to .63 than .62.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN)

> Rounding mode to round towards the "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even neighbor.
>   Behaves as for RoundingMode.HALF_UP if the digit to the left of the discarded fraction is odd; behaves as for RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN if it's even

In the case of:

```
250335.625
```

It is equidistant to `.62` and `.63` so it uses the left neighbor `2` which is `even` therefore is `HALF_DOWN`

In the case of:

```
250335.6250294325406169060513303508358832
```

It is closer to `.63` so it goes there.

If you try with `250335.615` you will see that is both equidistant to `.61` and `.62` but the left neighbor `1` is `odd` so it goes `HALF_UP`.

Giving `250335.62`

Answer (score 4):

`RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN` round to the **nearest neighbor** - when you have `0.62502` the number is closer to `0.63` than to `0.62`. It would round to the even number only if the difference is the same - the fractional part ends in 5.